# How to change Opera's source search highlighting color?

Tags: search, opera, source-code, highlighting

Opera offers brilliant incremental search while searching ona website but when it comes to source searching ( `Right button click -> Source -> Search` ) it is not so beautiful.

By default : when you search for a word in Source it highlights with nearly transparent grey color which is really hard to distinguish from normal text.

Does anyone know how to change this - the highlight color ?

P.S. I am using 11.61, build 1250

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Unpack and open file "skin.ini" from your current skin pack: **opera:config#UserPrefs|ButtonSet** 
   Standard path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\skin\standard_skin.zip\skin.ini
2. Close Opera.
3. In `[Generic]` add `Selected Text bgcolor nofocus = #your hex color` 
   for example #F0FF00

[image: Example of skin.ini]

Save and pack it back to standard_skin.zip and launch Opera

Comment: hmmm.. somehow this does not work for me :/

Comment: @Patryk It works fine for me (Opera 11.61 @ Win XP, default skin). Could you upload your **skin.ini**? I'll check it.

Comment: I use the same verison as you and Win 7 [link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Ti48JU0h) and I keep my skin in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\skin\standard_skin.zip`

Comment: You have `Selected Text background color nofocus` instead `Selected Text bgcolor nofocus`

Comment: I have tried this before but somehow didn't work and now when I changed it back to `bgcolor` it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `Preferences > Programs > Advanced > Choose application for viweing source` and choose a feature-rich app (Like notpade++) for source viewing instead of manually changing colors.