# Changing Opera's source search highlighting color?

Tags: opera, highlighting, source-code

I'm running Opera 12.01 and the highlighting color for source searching is a very very faint gray - barely distinguishable.

After looking at this thread
[How to change Opera's source search highlighting color?](https://superuser.com/questions/391323/how-to-change-operas-source-search-highlighting-color/510787)
I tried adding that line of code and re-zipping it with the default windows compressor. Completely screwed it up, program fails right away once started.

I get a black prompt, hardly readable with the "**send report**" option. I know cause I've gotten that Opera crash screen before, so I recognize the partial prompts I can actually read, but otherwise I wouldn't know what that prompt is about.

So I reverted back to the old zip. I tried a different program to zip, and that seemed to indeed change the content of the `ini` in the `.zip` file, however when I start the browser though - the highlight doesn't change color. Any ideas?

I made sure the is correctly entered. Copied/pasted directly from the skin.ini file (inside the standard_skin.zip file)

Selected Text `bgcolor nofocus = #116180`

Answer (score 0):

As no one has answered yet I will, but I've been away from my computer for a long long time... In short you've probably made it harder than you needed to. Call on > opera:config < in the address field then simply search highlight color or just color, you should find soon enough. If not, google your request and add > Tamil's blog < It's the best place to find great Opera tips.

Comment: Yeah - The first thing i did was to try the local config file through the browser. No dice.

The options there are: Highlighted Background, Highlighted Background Unfocused, Highlighted Text, Highlighted Text Unfocused. None of these is the one i'm looking for. Plus - i wouldn't think that if this was that easy the steps in the link above on how to edit the default skin .zip file would have been necessary.

Comment: I can't really believe I'm the only one that has the issue. The highlight is very irritatingly faint. Find it hard to believe there's no hack for this somewhere (like that list of steps ... just didn't work for me).

Comment: Confirming that one or the other language is disabled after fresh installation. Go to settings and enable it. (Latest Opera 99.x)